# Node.js - How can I remove the port from the url?

Tags: url, node.js, port, socket.io

I use the node.js and socket.io.

My application runs on the port 3000. The application starts from from the url: **mydomain.com:3000/**

I want to run the application from **mydomain.com** - I want to remove the port from the url.

Where and how can I set this setting?

Comment: Also the search would brought this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303690/nodejs-domain-without-port-number

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Find your [`server.listen`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#server.listen) call and change the port from `3000` to `80`. Don't forget that you have to run the program with the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability (see `capabilities(7)` for details) in order to bind to ports less than 1024 on Linux systems. `root` privilege will contain this, and other, privileges.

Comment: I tried to set the port to 80 The application was dropped. It's forbidden.

Comment: "The application was dropped"? What does that mean? Are you running it as `root`? Can you?

Comment: Conosle writes line: info  - socket.io started,
   warn  - error raised: Error: EACCES, Permission denied

Comment: Running the command as `root` would solve the issue but that would make your site extremely insecure. The proper solution is to use a Reverse Proxy and then bind a directory, say "mydomain.com/app" to the port 3000.

Comment: How to run in windows Machine

Comment: @Trojan, I don't think Windows has any restrictions on who can open low ports. If you're still having trouble, I recommend starting a new question with a ten-line program that demonstrates your problem. That will draw more attention from more experts. Thanks.

Comment: Running your node.js server application on port 80 is not considered safe.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to run it "without a port" like you describe, you're actually going to be running it on port 80.  You can't do this without root permissions.

So instead of

```
node server.js
```

You need

```
sudo node server.js
```

This is assuming you have sudo permissions on the machine you're trying to run it on.  Otherwise you're going to run into EACCESS problems.  That's what sarnold is trying to tell you.

Comment: how to run in Windows system

Comment: Down voting, cause running your node.js application on port 80 is not considered safe.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I did it because I'm using apache as well I can't use port 80 because it reserves it. So, I setup a proxy pass. I set my /src folder to be ignored.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/www.mysite.com"
    ServerName local.www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias local.www.mysite.com
    ProxyPass /src !
    ProxyPass / http://local.www.mysite.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://local.www.mysite.com:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do exactly the same thing but failed. In errorlog it says `[Fri Nov 29 18:45:45 2013] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt
 to connect to my.IP.addr.0:3000 (www.mydomainname.com) failed`. Which proxy module you are using (http, ftp, ajp etc.)?

Comment: Hey Charles- I am using the default apache setup for proxies. The only thing I changed to make the proxy work was this bit in my vhosts. My apache config has all the proxy modules loading. And apache is listening to port 80 in my config. Are you not loading any of the modules?

Answer (score 3):

First, you probably want to be running the application from your localhost, "127.0.0.1". You can remove the port just by omitting it in the node.js setup. By default, web browsers look for servers on port 80. If you want your server running on port 3000 for some reason, it will have to be included in the URL.

Comment: There is no solution? It has to go set the application to run on the server on this port without url.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I do not believe there is a way to run on port 3000 without including this in the URL. I could be wrong though.