# nodejs domain without port number

Tags: node.js, url, port

I have deployed my nodejs app on a VPS(ubuntu 10.04). I have hosted it on a subdomain (subdomain.myapp.com:3000) and I just have one IP address

By default port 80 is been used by apache as default. I just want that my app should run on port 3000 but URL should be (subdomain.myapp.com)

Is this possible in nodejs or do I have to tweak my virtual host or apache's files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is possible

In your apache virtual host file configure with the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.myapp.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

You should have

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

on top of your file and also Proxy module installed for apache ( I think it is a default configuration for ubuntu )

```
LoadModule proxy_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so
```

it must be in your httpd.conf file

then you should restart apache and it must be fine!

Comment: do I need to change this `ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/` to `ProxyPass / http://subdomain.myapp.com:3000/`

Comment: nope ... just leave it like that and run node on localhost:3000 as a separate process

Comment: Question is on nodejs, but answer is on apache, is that intentional or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Basav thats intentional, at least when it comes to deploying a NodeJS app on a server without the port number Apache (or Nginx) is absolutely needed. NodeJS is not a complete replacement of Apache/Nginx.

Comment: By the way, there are 2 modules that need to be loaded, on some distros you need to enable both, these 2 modules can be enabled with the commands "a2ensite proxy" and "a2ensite proxy_http".

Comment: It doesn't works for me , can anyone help me in this

Comment: no its "a2enmod proxy" & "a2enmod proxy_http", as it is model.

Comment: @drinchev how about multi node application? such as running application on 3000,3030 and 3333 ports?

Comment: I actually had to change the localhost to  127.0.0.1,

Answer (score 3):

Just an update of @drinchev answer with **Apache 2.4.***

Enable the proxy mode :

```
a2ensite proxy_http
a2ensite proxy
```

Then :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.myapp.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: While trying to fix this issue, I read that Apache needs to be "secured" before proxies are used. Do you know what that entails? Also, it seems that these proxies are enabled by default on AWS EC2 instances (I only had to add the VirtualHost to make it work). Does this mean Apache is "secure" on EC2?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing and @drinchev's answer almost worked for me, but because I run several vhosts on my dev box it didn't quite. A couple minor tweaks kept it from clobbering all my other vhosts.

```
<Proxy *>
```

Needed to be

```
<Proxy mynodejs.mydevbox.local>
```

And

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Needed to be

```
<VirtualHost mynodejs.mydevbox.local:80>
```

So where my local dev machine is named "mydevbox.local" and my node vhost is listening on port 3000, my final config looked more like:

```
<VirtualHost mynodejs.mydevbox.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/mynodejs"
    ServerName mynodejs.mydevbox.local
    ServerAlias mynodejs.mydevbox.local

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy mynodejs.mydevbox.local>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mynodejs_error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mynodejs_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost myothervhost.mydevbox.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/myothervhost"
    ServerName myothervhost.mydevbox.local
    ServerAlias myothervhost.mydevbox.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myothervhost_error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myothervhost_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Other vhosts could follow