# how to set node js app on default port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have Apache also running on my machine, I have to run my application without adding a port number.

It works when I access it from http://localhost:2121 using the following:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('hello');
}).listen(2121);
console.log('Server running');
```

How do I set it to use http://localhost (without the port number at the end.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - How can I remove the port from the url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526500/node-js-how-can-i-remove-the-port-from-the-url)

Comment: you just do `.listen(80)` - however, if apache is running on port 80 already it wont work as you can't have two servers listening on the same port.

Comment: Probably it is time to learn something more about **Apache mod-proxy** add-on and how redirect traffic from :80 to :2121

Comment: good Question buddy @vikrant.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is occupying Port 80 for you. If you try to start your node server with port 80 (assuming your apache is up) you will get a permission error. The right approach is to reverse proxy your node app and serve it via apache. Your apache config should look like the following.

```
         <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName localhost
           ServerAlias localhost
           DocumentRoot /path/to/your/node/app
           Options -Indexes
           ProxyRequests on
           ProxyPass / http://localhost:2121/
         </VirtualHost>
```

Also, my advise to you is to use Nginx if possible, makes life a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

By default http port runs on 80 port so if you do like this

`

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('hello');
}).listen(80);
console.log('Server running');
```

`

You will be able to access your content at [http://localhost/](http://localhost)

Also remember you cannot run more than one application on one port . It will not work.