# Express app dont listen without port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im new with node and a have a problem with express, my app only listen to localhost:PORT and i wanna to the app listen to localhost too, heres is my code,

**

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('App');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, 'localhost');
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

**

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526500/node-js-how-can-i-remove-the-port-from-the-url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526500/node-js-how-can-i-remove-the-port-from-the-url)

Comment: thanks is this what im looking for

Answer (score 1):

You cannot listen without a port, because that would not make any sense. Every TCP connection needs to happen over *some* port. What you are looking for is the default 80 port for http, or 443 for https. The browser uses these ports by default.

Depending on the configuration of your system, a user space program may not necessarily have access to these ports. So you may have to configure your system to grant your node application access.

Comment: you are ignoring the application port set on their definitions, but this config is commonly used in http server