# Remove port number from URL

Tags: node.js, apache, httpd.conf

I am very new to nodejs . I am using (Godaddy)WHM (apache 2.2.3) .

I am referring following link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345829/6299548

but I am not finding the httpd.conf file in my WHM.

I have also tried for following from my WHM.
(Home >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> Global Configuration)

How to take backup of my old httpd.conf file, Edit the file and add new content given by Anna.

Can you give me the steps for 
1) Go to httpd.conf
2) Take backup of old httpd.conf
3) Add new content given by Anna

Comment: you want to remove port from url? Is something like this `www.domain.com:3000` to `www.domain.com` ??

Comment: Yes myfriend exactly

Comment: If you are trying to find the location of httpd.conf, then GoDaddy support may be a better route. https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/where-is-httpd-conf.117485/ also gives a few pointers.

Comment: If you terminal access, then try to locate it. `locate httpd.conf`

Comment: to remove port assign hostname to localhost:3000 in host file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove port number from url unless it is default port such as 80 or 443.

You can mask it if you reverse proxy, but still your frontend port would have to be 80 or 443.