# Access Node.js server by URL without port at the end

Tags: node.js, apache, express, url, port

My server is running on a Node.js environment with Express. My server works fine, but I can't remove the port at the end of the domain name from the URL.

What is the right way to access my app with an URL without port at the end ?

Comment: Please refer this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526500/node-js-how-can-i-remove-the-port-from-the-url.

Comment: no help .......i already change server.listen to 80 , but it generate an error while starting node app .

Comment: I already use Virtual  hosting in Lamp server .. but it can't resolve my issue .

Comment: Find which program is listening on port `80` and stop it then try running nodejs again.

Comment: i have xammp then apache is runing  on 80 port

Comment: What is your error when you change to port 80 ? What do you mean by simple url ? What do you mean by "can't run without starting from the terminal" ?

Comment: Could you let me know if i answered your question ?

Answer (score 17):

#### Client side

---

By default, the port is **80** when a browser make an HTTP request.

If you type `localhost`, the real request is `localhost:80` because no port is specified. It will be the same with any domain name. If you type `example.com`, the real request is `example.com:80`.

It is the client (here the browser) which choose on which port it will make his request to the server.

You can force your browser to emit a request on any port by adding *:port_number* after the domain name, as `localhost:3000` or `example.com:3000`. Here we change the port from **80** to **3000**.

#### Server side

---

The web server chooses on which port it listens for requests. It can be **80**, **3000** or any other port.

If a client makes an HTTP request, your web server needs to listen to the right port. If the client emits `example.com:4000`, your web server must listen on port **4000** to get and process the request.

To make a web server, you can use Node.js, Apache (used in LAMP), Nginx etc. You can have multiple web servers running on your system and each of them can use multiple ports, but you can't make them listen on the same port. One of your web server may not start or could take the lead on others or crash...

Solutions are to use only one web server or to use multiple web server on different ports. In your situation, you are using LAMP so Apache web server. Its probably running on port **80** in his configuration. In this case you can't run a Node web server on port **80** because it's already in use. You should choose another port like **3000** for example. Both Node and Apache will then run on your system but on different ports respectively **3000** and **80**.

In this last situation, you can access directly to Apache, but not to Node without precise the port **3000**. To be able to access Node web server by port **80** without stopping Apache, you need to go through Apache and to make it redirect requests to your Node server in some cases. To do that, you need to configurate a proxy in your Apache. Note that it would be the same if you was using Nginx or other web servers.

#### Example

---

Let's take a simple express server on port 3000 :

```
// server.js  
var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        http = require('http').createServer(app),
        port = 3000;

app.get('*', function (req, res, next) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html'); });

http.listen(port, function () { console.log('App running & listening on port ' + port); });
```

- If you type in the terminal `node server.js`, you can access from browser by `localhost:3000`, but you can't access by `localhost` because no web server is running on port **80**.
- If you change port variable to 80, you can access from browser by `localhost` or `localhost:80`, but not by `localhost:3000` anymore.
- If you edit `/etc/hosts` (sudo nano /etc/hosts) with a new line `127.0.0.1 example.com`, you can access from browser by `example.com` if port is **80**, else *example.com:port_number* like `example.com:3000`. **This third solution maps domain name to ip address in your local client only.**

If the chosen port, **80** for example, is already in use by another process (as LAMP), your node server may not works. In this case you should close this other process first or choose another port for your node process. In the third example, if you close the LAMP first, you can access from browser by **example.com**, if you choose another port for Node, you can access from browser by example.com:port_number like `example.com:3000` for Node and still access your LAMP server on port **80**.

Don't forget that **80** is the default port used by the browser if no port is specified. If you use another port, you should precise it from the browser by adding *:port_number* after your domain.

- Now if you own a real domain name you will need to make a real DNS mapping not juts edit `/etc/hosts`. Configure your DNS on your registar account (where you bought your domain name) to make it point to your server's IP. Like that, when a client make an HTTP request to the domain name, it will be redirected to your server.
- To have both Apache and Node.js running and available on port **80**, you should make a proxy as explain above. Indeed, for you the problem is probably that you have a web server already running on port **80** (Apache with LAMP) and you want also your Node.js app to run on port **80** to don't force clients to precise the port at the end of the url. To fix that, you need to make a proxy in Apache conf to redirect requests which come from the specific domain name to your localhost node server process on the right port.

Something like that in your apache conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here when a request arrive on your server on port **80**, Apache will check if it comes from `example.com` and if it is, it will redirect to `127.0.0.1:3000` where your node server will take the lead. The two different process (Apache & Node) should run in the same time on your server on different port.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run your node js server without any port and simply by http://localhost then listen your express js server on port 80 .

Answer (score 4):

You could either do as stated by the previous answers and run on port 80 
 OR 
 you could keep the server running on whatever port you want and setup a proxy server such as [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) and forward the HTTP requests to said server. 
This could be helpful in case you want to spin up multiple instances or even different processes.

Comment: That's pretty much what i explained about multiple web servers & proxy ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you see a URL, without a port, it means one of two ports are being served:

- **https://** - port 443
- **http://** - port 80

**Even assuming the port is not in use**, you can't service directly to port 80 without superuser privileges because port 80 and port 443 are privileged ports.

If you want to test the server running on port 80 directly:

```
sudo node index.js
```

Where index.js is the name of your Express application.

*Keeping it running*

Because you tagged `apache`, I'm assuming you want to know how to set up a node server using Apache. If you don't need a production quality server and just want to keep it running all the time, you can do that too.

**Dev/Just keep it running**

You can daemonize your server. A quick look for a "node" solution exposes [forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903570/how-does-one-start-a-node-js-server-as-a-daemon-process) as a way to do that. Simply install and run like this:

```
yarn global add forever
# or
# npm i -g forever
# remember, sudo for port 80
sudo forever start index.js
```

**Production/Apache**

Use a non-privileged port for Node, and set up a proxy in Apache. Something like:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000
```

If you set the port to 8000. Put that in a `<VirtualHost>`. Examples [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/429404/help-me-understand-how-to-use-proxypass). Likely you would still want to daemonize your nodejs Application using `forever` or some similar daemon tool ([systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426862/proper-way-to-run-shell-script-as-a-daemon) is great for Linux services)